# Lightning Lookups

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lookup, lightning-apps

I'm having a problem while I'm developing a lightning component.
I have taken a attribute of type Custom object and using that displaying a Input field which s coming like a lookup and putting the value and saving that till here it is woking fine after getting success i just wanna make this field empty or null but its not being possible I tried lots of ways.

[image]

```
<force:inputField value="{!v.fumoSplit.Funtional_Unit__c}" required="true" aura:id="functionalUnit" />
```

It is coming using above syntax.

and I tried following syntaxes to make it empty:

```
component.find("functionalUnit").set("v.value", fumoSplit2.Funtional_Unit__c);
component.find("functionalUnit").set("v.value",null);
component.set("v.fumoSplit", null);
```

But unable to make it blank.

Comment: I think, we need full code of component, controller and helper, in order to help you

Comment: give me your email Id i'll send you @AlexanderBerehovskiy

Comment: @ArkshAy you can post it in your question :) just edit it

Comment: Please check now

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer:
var funitLookup = component.find('auraid').get('v.body')[0];
                funitLookup.updateValues();